# Method is not called in CoffeeScript

Tags: coffeescript

I try to create a class with a method and then call this method. But the alert() is never executed. Why??

```
class Demo
    constructor: (text) ->
      @text = text
    demo: ->
      alert @text

d = new Demo "Hallo"
console.log d
d.demo
```

Comment: Did you read the documentation? This is covered in the first few paragraphs: http://coffeescript.org/#language

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Functions must be called with parens if there are no arguments.

`d.demo` should be `d.demo()`.